# jQuery scrollTop not working inside iframe on Iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

This works everywhere, except for iframe on iOS.

the example is as

when you click on a category it should scroll , only I have the problem that it doesn't work on IOS

https://codepen.io/fdemian/full/ZjpXBe

I used

```
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: offsetTop }, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to animate $("body") and not $("html, body") because the mobile ios doesn’t know it

Comment: this does not work @OiramDEV. Can you please provide a sample? It needs to work on an iPhone. That is the only place it does not work.

Comment: I testesd it again. Seeing other solutions, the following function worked for me:
 -  window.scrollTo(x, y) for smartphone (apple, android)
 - $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x, scrollLeft: y}, milliseconds) for pc

Answer (score 0):

I testesd it again. Seeing other solutions, the following function worked for me:

- for smartphone (apple, android)

```
    window.scrollTo(x, y)
```

- for pc

```
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: x, scrollLeft: y}, milliseconds)
```